# Where (in an object3d) can I find the changing point coordinates?

Tags: javascript, three.js

This shows one point rotating around the Y axis.
I want to see the changing X coordinate as it rotates.
This shows the starting coordinate, but it doesn't change.
The varying coordinates must be somewhere, right?  Where?
I thought "pointa.geometry.vertices[0].x" would be the place.

EDIT: I made the rotating point a rotating Group under a fixed Scene.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> a point </title>
    <script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  "use strict";
  var js3canvas, renderer, camera, world, pointa, geometry, material, datadiv;
  var norotate;
window.onload = function() { 
  "use strict";
  js3canvas = document.getElementById("js3canvas");
  datadiv = document.getElementById("data");
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas:js3canvas } );
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 1, 1, 20);
  camera.position.set(0,5,10);
  camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
  norotate = new THREE.Scene();
  norotate.background = new THREE.Color(0x888888);
  world = new THREE.Group();
  norotate.add(world);
  // make point
  geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(2.3456,0,0));
  material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { color:0xffffff } );
  pointa = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
  world.add(pointa);
  animate();
}
function animate() { 
  datadiv.innerHTML = "X coordinate: " + pointa.geometry.vertices[0].x; // the x coordinate
  renderer.render( norotate, camera );
  world.rotateY(.03);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas width="200" height="200" id="js3canvas"></canvas>
    <div id="data"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like the x coordinate of the point isn't actually changing - you're rotating the whole scene, not changing the point's position. I'm not sure what coordinate you actually want..?

Comment: @Matthew Adams  If the world is going around, I would think the coordinates would have to change.

Comment: I guess the WebGL is more magical than I thought.

Comment: I think the coordinates are *relative* to the world. E.g., if you're driving in your car, your position (read: coordinates) in the car isn't changing, even though the car itself is moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change rotation or position or scale of an object, you apply just a transform matrix to the points of a geometry, keeping data of the points intact.

Set a temp vector, copy a vertex into this vector, cast from local to world coordinate system:

```js
var js3canvas, renderer, camera, world, pointa, geometry, material, datadiv;
var norotate;
js3canvas = document.getElementById("js3canvas");
datadiv = document.getElementById("data");
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: js3canvas
});
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 1, 1, 20);
camera.position.set(0, 5, 10);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
norotate = new THREE.Scene();
norotate.background = new THREE.Color(0x888888);
world = new THREE.Group();
norotate.add(world);
// make point
geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(2.3456, 0, 0));
material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  color: 0xffffff
});
pointa = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
world.add(pointa);
var tempV3 = new THREE.Vector3();
animate();

function animate() {
  pointa.localToWorld(tempV3.copy(pointa.geometry.vertices[0]));
  datadiv.innerHTML = "X coordinate: " + tempV3.x; // the x coordinate
  renderer.render(norotate, camera);
  world.rotateY(.03);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200" id="js3canvas"></canvas>
<div id="data"></div>
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Just what I wanted!  I've got some studying to do.  If I have a question, can I call you?  :)

Comment: @dcromley You're welcome :) Feel free to ask questions on the forum: https://discourse.threejs.org